# How to add new key for each dict with jq streaming mode

Tags: json, jq

I have a json below, I need to use stream mode(file is huge) to parse the data then convert it to another data structure

```
{
  "id": {
    "bioguide": "E000295",
    "thomas": "02283",
    "govtrack": 412667
  },
  "bio": {
    "gender": "F",
    "birthday": "1970-07-01"
  },
  "tooldatareports": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "tooldata": [
        {
          "toolid": {
            "value": 12345
          },
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "toolid": {
            "value": 12346
          },
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Use below command line can get the most data that I expect
but in each dict, have some key do not  have value, such as bioguide, thomas, name, toolid

```
cat data.json | jq -cn --stream '[fromstream(inputs | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:]) | . +{"bioguide":.id.bioguide[0], "thomas":.id.thomas, "name":.tooldatareports[0].name, "toolid":.tooldatareports[0].tooldata.toolid.value}]'
```

My expected result is

```
[
  {
    "bioguide": "E000295",
    "thomas": "02283",
    "name": "A",
    "toolid": 12345,
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "bioguide": "E000295",
    "thomas": "02283",
    "name": "A",
    "toolid": 12346,
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -nM --stream '
 [fromstream( 
   inputs
   | (.[0] | index("id")) as $ix
   | if $ix then .[0] |= .[1+$ix:] 
     else (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix
     | if $ix then .[0] |= .[$ix:]
       else (.[0] | index("tooldatareports")) as $ix
       | (.[0][$ix:] | index("name")) as $jx
       | if $jx then (.[0] |= .[$ix+$jx:] )
         else (.[0] | index("toolid")) as $ix
         | if $ix then .[0] |= .[$ix:] 
           else empty
           end
         end
       end
     end
 )]
| .[0] as $general
| [.[1:][] 
   | ($general + .)
   | {bioguide,thomas,name,toolid,data} ]
' input.json
```

Comment: oops, it's complicated, But the name in the second dict seems null